# Distributing $k$ balls into $n$ bins with two conditions

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I have $n$ bins and $k$ balls such that $n \lt 2k$.

In how many ways can I distribute the $k$ balls in the $n$ bins subject to following constraints:

- 1)  A bin gets max one ball.
- 2)  No two successive bins are empty.

Not sure if there is a clean solution to this. Have been thinking about it for a bit.

Comment: The phrase "successive bins" implies the bins are in some sort of order - is this linear or cyclic?

Comment: I dont know what is meant by cyclic vs linear but the bins are placed in a line 1..n. You then place the balls in the bins. Two successive bins can have a ball each but there should be no two successive empty bins. Also at most one ball per bin.

Comment: OK. That's what I meant by linear. It makes a difference if they are placed in a circle.

Answer (score 4):

Let $1$ stands for an empty bin and $0$ stands for a full bin. You want to count how many strings like $0100100101$ are there, with length $n$, exactly $k$ zeroes in them and no consecutive $1$s. You may build such strings by first placing $k$ consecutive zeroes, then choosing $n-k$ places (among the $k+1$ spaces between consecutive zeroes, at the beginning or at the end) where to put a $1$.

The answer is so given by $\large\binom{k+1}{n-k}$ due to [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).